# Instagram realtime API rate limits

Tags: api, instagram, rate-limiting

I was using Instagram realtime API for some time and everything was working fine. I have only one subscription on users.

Lately it started to behave totally strange. I'm not getting all of the content, and there's no way to find any pattern. Every request triggers a log right when it hits my server so I can tell whether or not Instagram notifies me about the new content pretty accurately.

I'm starting to suspect that rate-limit is causing this problems. Does anybody knows if there's some rate-limit that can cause that behavior? Did anybody else have similar problems with the Instagram real-rime API ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rate limit of 5000/post/hour [BY experience and best of my knowledge]

However Instagram is very good in explaining the root cause so, if you see the error message it would clearly say "RateLimitExceeded" or what ever the root cause may be.